# What is a good way to split the .wtv files for Media Center PC recorded TV programs that are 25GB?

Tags: tv, video-editing, hdtv, media-center

I am using Windows 7 and recording some winter Olympics programs on TV.  A lot of times, the programs can be 17GB or 25GB long.  (now the extension is .wtv)

What if I want to just keep 2 minutes of the program, such as a Mogul Skiing run for the gold medal, or the Skating program which I like best?

I think Media Center doesn't have a built in tool to split a video.  Are there tools that is easy and capable of doing it?  a 2 minute program probably will be only 200MB for 1920 x 1080 resolution, and will be much easier to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (depending on which edition of Windows 7 you have) be able to right click on the .wtv files and "Convert to .dvr-ms format" or use a 3rd party tool like [ToDVRMS](http://babgvant.com/blogs/andyvt/archive/2010/02/05/todvrms-1-0-1-4.aspx)

From [Wikipedia DVR-MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVR-MS):

> Windows 7 includes built-in support for converting non copy-protected WTV files to DVR-MS.[9]  Third party tools also exist to convert WTV to DVR-MS such as Andy VT's ToDVRMS

You can then edit the .dvr-ms using [Windows Live Movie Maker](http://download.live.com/moviemaker)

Comment: great, turns out Movie Maker can actually take .wtv  but it seems that if i export the TV as a 720p file, it is not as good quality as the original video shown by Media Center in a window that is about the size of 720p.

Comment: Play about with the encoding settings a bit - increase the bitrate, change the resize filter (if that is possible with Movie Maker?)

If you leave it at 1080p then it shouldn't need to re-encode at all.